# Why does the twilio sendgrid login help page force users to login?

Tags: twilio, sendgrid

I have a Twilio sendgrid account and I am not receiving 2FA messages - I don't know the reason why.

According to:  https://support.sendgrid.com/hc/en-us  I am instructed to click "Trouble Logging in?"  and choose from one of four reasons I cannot login.

*All four of those reasons lead immediately to a login screen*

So, in summary, if you have issues logging in, you need to login first to get help.

This is so laughably bad that I assume somehow I am at fault.  This is my error somehow - it is *inconceivable* that the sendgrid help/support page actually works like this.

What is my error ?  Thanks.

Comment: I am a developer evangelist at Twilio. I agree, this is wrong and I'm going to bring it up internally. I am voting to close this question though, as it's not something that can be answered on Stack Overflow. Sorry you're having this problem right now though.

Comment: For the time being I will continue to not login to sendgrid and my applications and use-cases will just stay broken.  What is so ironic about this is that I don't want to use sendgrid and I have no reason to be a sendgrid (paying) customer - but twilio REFUSES to let us email from twiml so I have to build a fragile, complicated bridge between twilio and sendgrid just to CC: my alert SMS to an email inbox.  Sigh.

Comment: Hey, I understand that being locked out is frustrating and that the frustration is doubled when the support site also tells you to log in. I can also tell you that I'd love to see an `<Email>` verb in TwiML, but for now you do need to send email via an API call instead. I'd hope the bridge wasn't too complicated, I built [a Twilio Function that forwards an SMS to email](https://github.com/twilio-labs/function-templates/blob/main/forward-message-sendgrid/functions/forward-message-sendgrid.protected.js) and I hope it wouldn't be much more than that.

Comment: You can also email directly to help@sendgrid.com to get help accessing your account. Please include the username or email of the account admin.

Comment: Yes, that is almost identical to the function I use to cc: SMS to email using sendgrid.  Again, needlessly complex but you can't fight city hall.  Cheers.

Comment: An update here ... sendgrid is offering to let me reset the account by proving myself with my PI key, which I have.  And they asked me to send my API key to sendgridtesting@gmail.com ... they want me to send my API key to a gmail account.  Is this an April fools joke ?

Comment: To be clear, you have been asked to send an email to that gmail address _using your API credentials_, *not* sending your API credentials. You have a pass phrase to send to that email address, to identify the email. I don’t know exactly what the support team does with this, but my assumption is that they will look for the correctly sent email in the SendGrid logs to prove that you are the owner of the account.

Comment: This is ridiculous, I just stumbled across the same problem. I'm not receiving the 2fA text messages anymore to log in, and looking for help in the support section it tells me I have to be logged in to access the help. 3 months don't seem to have been enough to fix this.

Comment: Same here, ha ha. My account is being locked for two month already, cos they are forcing me to login to figure out login issues. Sendgrid - sucks.

Comment: am stuck here too. Any help pls...

Comment: Same issue for me too @philnash

Comment: As I said in comments above, you can contact SendGrid by emailing help@sendgrid.com directly. I also no longer work at Twilio so I can't help these issues directly.

Comment: One and a half years passed and the issue is still the same. Additionally the help@sendgrid.com email address has been shut down.